# Какой вариант среди приведённых правилен?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мясо, запечённое под сыром. 
Мясо, запечённое с сыром. 
Мясо запечёное, с сыром. 
Мясо запечённое, под сыром.

Почему удвоенное н необходимо, только когда есть зависимое слово? Ведь запечь - глагол сов. вида.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенный вид глагола "запечь" образовался из несовершенного при помощью приставки **за-** (*печь — **за**печь*), поэтому от него получается только причастие (а не прилагательное!) и только с суффиксом **–енн** — **запечённый.**

Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F):
Правильно: запечённый лосось; печёный картофель; куриная грудка, запечённая с картофелем.
Слово в полной форме с суффиксом *-н-(-нн-), -ен-(-енн)-* является отглагольным прилагательным, если оно образовано от глагола несовершенного вида (например: печёный от *печь* – что делать?) и не имеет зависимых слов, и **является причастием, если образовано от глагола совершенного вида** (например: запечённый от *запечь* – что сделать?) и/или имеет зависимые слова.

Делаем вывод: во всех примерах, приведенных вами, правильно писать **запечённый**.

Дополнение
Образование прилагательного возможно только с отрицанием **не-** (и, соответственно, с суфиксом **–ен**). Например, незапечёный – это признак, не зависящий от того, запекали ли мы мясо или нет (глагола "незапечь" не существует).

Comment: А как правильно, "под сыром" и "с сыром"

Comment: ПОД – нахождение ниже чего-либо + соответственно Т. п.: под сыром, под майонезом (покрыта вся поверхность). **С** чем – продукт (сыр) может находиться внутри блюда, вперемежку, слоями, то есть не обязательно покрыта вся поверхность.

Answer (score 0):

Мясо, запечённое под сыром - мясо пеклось вместе с сыром; сыр покрывал мясо сверху. 
 
Мясо, запечённое с сыром - мясо пеклось с сыром; сыр был утыкан в мясе или вложен в разрезы в мясе, а может, сыр был положен рядом. 
Мясо запечённое, с сыром - мясо пеклось отдельно, после запекания (при подаче к столу) был положен сыр: рядом или в разрезы на мясе. 
Мясо запечённое, под сыром - мясо пеклось отдельно, после запекания (при подаче к столу) был положен сыр, чтобы покрывал поверхность мяса.

Comment: Вопрос про орфографию, а не кулинарию

Comment: Дык, надо знать, что человеку хочется выразить. Он выберет свой вариант, о котором спрашивает - вот и ответ на орфографию. И где звучит про орфографию?